# Modifying the content of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have a long list of form

```
{{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8}, ... {97,98,99,100}}
```

how do I edit/convert it by adding the text as shown below

```
{{1,2,3,4} -> group1, {5,6,7,8} -> group1, ... {97,98,99,100} -> group3}
```

(I want to prepare data for machine learning.)

That is, how to add something (not an element) to the end of an existing sub-list. I've discovered how to read in large datasets suitably prepared in a text editor (using `ReadList`), but I'm wondering how to do the editing within *Mathematica*.

Surely this sort of editing is possible but I cannot find how to do it in the *Documentation*. I'm probably mis-understanding something quite simple.

Comment: Do you want the output to be a list of replacement rules `list -> label` or a list of just labels (strings)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume the multiplicity of group names in your example is not a typo, that is, you might want to name multiple sublists with the same group. Either way, this will do what you want:

```
(* example list and group names *)
list = Partition[Range@20, 4];
groups = {"group1", "group1", "group2", "group2", "group3"};
Rule @@@ Transpose[{list, groups}]

(* 
   {{1, 2, 3, 4} -> "group1", {5, 6, 7, 8} -> "group1", 
   {9, 10, 11, 12} -> "group2", {13, 14, 15, 16} -> "group2", 
   {17, 18, 19, 20} -> "group3"} 
*)
```

*n.b.* - see *Guess who it is*'s comment re: more direct and canonical way of doing last step. DOH on my part...

Comment: `Thread[list -> groups]` is what I usually do.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.: Ah, yeah, I herp-a-derped on that obvious and better way - was working on something deep, and over-thought above - you know how that goes...

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[1];list = RandomInteger[100, {6, 4}];
i = 1; j = 1; Sequence @@@ ({# -> "group" <> ToString[i++], #2 -> 
          "group" <> ToString[j++]} & @@@ Partition[list, {2}])
(*{{80, 14, 0, 67} -> "group1", {3, 65, 100, 23} -> 
  "group1", {97, 68, 74, 15} -> "group2", {24, 4, 100, 90} -> 
  "group2", {83, 70, 1, 30} -> "group3", {48, 25, 44, 73} -> "group3"}*)
```